# Toggle show hide for multiple divs with one button

Tags: java, html, button, toggle

I am trying to toggle multiple divs with same class via one button. At the moment, only the first div is doing the job and the rest gets ignored. I tried to change .getElementById to .getElementsByClassName but it also doesn´t do the trick. Can you please help? Here is my code. I´m trying since 2 days. :/

Code for Button:

```html
<input onclick="change();myFunction()" type="button" value="Zeige Features" id="myButton1"></input>
```

Code for changing the text of button when clicked to "hide" / "show" (in German):

```html
<script>function change() // no ';' here
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    if (elem.value=="Zeige Features") elem.value = "Verstecke Features";
    else elem.value = "Zeige Features";
}</script>
```

The problem should be perhaps here. That´s the code for toggling the divs but only the first div does it:

```html
<script>function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggle-div");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
} </script>
```

Hope u can help me, and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

this was a pain in the ass but I think with a lot of workaround I solved it. Here is what I wanted to achive. Having three buttons and three divs. When I click one button alls three divs disappear and all three buttons change text to "hide". When click again, vice versa. I hope this helps everyone out there. I think to trigger all "classes" is in css much easier. These were my first steps in javascript and it was as difficult as chinese for me (don´t speak it :)).

```js
// Toggle all buttons texts

function change() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("#button");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].value == "Zeige Features") {
      x[i].value = "Verstecke Features";
    } else {
      x[i].value = "Zeige Features";
    }
  }
}

// Toggle show and hide divs

function showhide() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("#toggle-div");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display =
        "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Inserting 3 buttons-->

<input onclick="change();showhide()" type="button" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></input>
<input onclick="change();showhide()" type="button" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></input>
<input onclick="change();showhide()" type="button" value="Zeige Features" id="button"></input>

<!--Inserting 3 divs-->

<div id="toggle-div"> div 1 </div>
<div id="toggle-div"> div 2 </div>
<div id="toggle-div"> div 3 </div>
```

Thanks @pikachu_on_acid. Youre approach was the right one but still I had issues with it. Don´t wonder if you have to click two times at the beginning when u want to hide the divs. In my site they are first hidden, so they appear fist. If you want to reverse that just change the values from "block" "none" "block" to "none" "block" "none" in the java code.

Thanks for your help and regards!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from your `onclick` and add a space.

```
//New code
<input onclick="change() myFunction()" type="button" value="Zeige Features" id="myButton1"></input>
```

The text of Button will change pretty easily onclick.

```
<script>
function change()
{
var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1"); 

    if (elem.value=="Zeige Features") elem.value = "Verstecke Features";
    else elem.value = "Zeige Features";

}//function closed
</script>
```

Use `getElementsByClass`, it will give an array, so loop through the array, and change the style of each div one by one.

```
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
  var x = document.getElementsByClass("toggle-div");

for( var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  if (x[i].style.display === "block") {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x[i].style.display = "block";
  }
}
} 
</script>
```

You can use any loop other then `for` also, or you can use `map()`

Comment: Hey, I´m not pretty sure if you are addressing my issue. Perhaps you thought I will fix the toggle for the text for the buttons, but that is working! I can´t get the problem toggling all of the divs with that one button... Still thx.

Comment: Sorry, nothing happens. Pasted it 1 to 1.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem yet?
If not please tell me that you want to hide/show all the divs on the click of the button simultaneously? I have given you the solution for one function only, wait I'll write for both.

Answer (score 0):

there are several problems here.
First of all you should get your element by class as it:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("name-of-toggle-divs-class");
```

this will return an HTMLCollection, so you want to cast it to an array, like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("name-of-toggle-divs-class"));
```

And then apply the style change to ALL of the elements. Resuming:

```
function myFunction(){
 const divArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("name-of-toggle-divs-class"));
 //Detecting the style you're going to use
 const displayStyle = divArray[0].display.style === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
 divArray.forEach(div => {
    div.style.display = displayStyle;
});
```

You should use class identifier because and id would suggest you have only one item. Let me know if you have problems.

You could also think of toggling class from your items defining class as:

```
 .div-of-toggle-divs-class{
   //some attributes
   display: block;
   &.invisible{
       display: none;
   }
  }
```

To do this just follow the same process as above and use the toggleClass method on the divArray elements. Try this:

```
<head>
     <style>
       .myClass {
             border: 1px solid black;
             margin-top: 2px;
             width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
      <script>
            function myFunction(){
            const divArray = 
            Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"));
           //Detecting the style you're going to use
           const displayStyle = divArray[0].display.style === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
          divArray.forEach(div => {
          div.style.display = displayStyle;
         }); 
      </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="myClass"></div>
        <div class="myClass"></div>
        <div class="myClass"></div>
        <button type="button" onclik="myFunction()">CLICK ME</button>
</body>
```

Comment: So do I have to add a different class name for every div? Is there not a possibility to avoid that? All the divs have the same class... I thought I could just change from id to class so that the code works for all divs at the same time. Or what do you mean with: ("name-of-toggle-divs-class")? I think I have not enough knowledge for this codes? :(

Comment: Nope you can, and you should, use the same class name for every div ! "name-of-toggle-divs-class" is the name of the class that you're going to add to that divs eg
<div class="hideble></div><div class="hideble></div><div class="hideble></div><div class="hideble></div><div class="hideble></div><div class="hideble></div>

Comment: Sorry, but nothing is happening when I use your code. I´m sure I´m doing something wrong. That´s what I did. I have my button as usual: 1.) <input onclick="change(); myFunction()" type="button" value="Zeige Features" id="myButton1"></input> 2.) I added all of your codes one by one in a single html file (every block of code u gave me in a single html file) in the site with <script>. I changed the class names to "name-of-toggle-divs-class" but nothing happens. I think I will never solve this.

Comment: I used it before posting. I'm sending you a pm with my code

Comment: Lol i don't know how to send a PM, i will post another answer with it